# Display the same TextView on every activity in an app/"permanent" textView?

Tags: java, android, textview

So I'm making a game and one of the central aspects of the game (like most other games) is how much money you have. So, on each activity I have a TextView that displays the players money (I have a "global" static variable setup so I can access the player's current money from anywhere in the app).

As of now, I have a bunch of different textViews with ids like "moneycount1, moneycount2, etc." and on each activity, when I resume the activity, I just set the textview to display the player's money.

However, is there any way to have a "permanent" textview, that will appear in the same location, and display the same information, on every single activity in the app? This would save a lot of time and repetition.

Thanks

Comment: i mean, u have to put it into the XML, but in the XML, you can add text. you can also create a global method that created a textview instance, with the text, etc etc... but again, you need to update the activity class with this method.

Comment: Create a separate layout file and write your `TextView` there, then, wherever you want to use it, simply make use of `<include>` .

Comment: i agree with you @TaseerAhmad, I was busy typing exactly that :D

Comment: Okay great, thanks a ton, I'll use the <include> tag!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each activity has to have its own layout, so this will probably not be possible. the first option I could think of to make life easier, would be to:

consider using the include tag, to include the same component in different layout files : https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

you simply make a layout file with your textview/components in and then use as:

`<include layout="@layout/yourLayoutName"/>`
in your layouts

alternatively, you could also have a single activity with different fragments in it, then store this global value in the activity, so that the fragments all have access to it OR maybe try build different layout files with this fragment inside it

have a look at this : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

which says that :

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in a
>   FragmentActivity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single
>   activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple
>   activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an
>   activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events,
>   and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of
>   like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

Comment: Ah interesting, haven't heard of the include tag before. Thanks a bunch (again!) :D

Comment: no worries @Evan, at least your questions are interesting, sooo tired at this point of seeing questions just asking for code, at least these are fun :D happy coding :P

Comment: Fragments is the way to go

Comment: i agree @COYG, but in my head I couldn't really think of a way it would work entirely, because you're changing activities either way, so the include tag might just be more useful, thoughts ?

Comment: I suspect that @Evan may not know about the usefulness of fragments and assumed the only way to make the content (navigate between different screen content) of the screen change is to create new activities. I would suggest making one activity of all his main components that needs to be displayed all the time and converting his existing activities into fragments. I made this exact misunderstanding before.

Comment: Oh damn I've never even heard of fragments before haha, I'm pretty new to Android Studio but been working on a game for over a month now, I'm gonna google them. Thanks!

Comment: usually, if a fragment is your answer to a problem, it involves reworking a few existing things, so I try to find alternative solutions before suggesting fragments, but in all honesty they do come up quite often as answers either way :D thanks for the talk @COYG

Comment: I wish I had known about fragments back when I was starting this. See, I had lots of issues with passing data between activities so I ended up just making a massive "global" static class that holds everything, but fragments are really handy! I think for now, I'm not going to rework my project with fragments, cuz I already have so much done, but next project I make, I'm definitely going to implement fragments. Thanks a ton guys :D

Comment: haha yeah that is true, it's tough learning without a uni class for Android dev! And yep I gotchu :)